# DOM traversal of table: Can't find anchors on rows

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

I have an html table like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
</head>
<body>

<table id="tableA">
    <a name="local1"><tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr></a>
    <a name="local2"><tr>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr></a>
</table>   

</body>
</html>
```

Anchors wrap the table rows because there is no telling which cell contains more lines of text content, and one of them has that content centered horizontally.  So using the anchors must take the page to the top of the row, not the top of the content in one particular cell, or else some work has to be done in js to determine how much to adjust the scroll by after the jump.

This works, but now I need to dynamically index those anchors using javascript, and I notice even traversing the entire table like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    traverse(document.getElementById('tableA'));
}

function traverse (node) {
    var kids = node.children;
    if (!kids) return;
    var len = kids.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        traverse(kids[i]);
        alert(node.tagName+" "+kids[i].tagName);
    }
}
```

I never find the anchor, yet doing the same thing with a simple paragraph:

```
<p><a name="local3">blah blah</a>
```

The anchor is the first child of the paragraph. What can I do?

Comment: this isn't strictly valid HTML.  a `TR` can only contain `TH` or `TD` elements, and a `TD` can't be a child of `a`.

Comment: @Claies Well that would explain that.  So there is then no way to create an anchor on a table row or cell?  I guess another question...

Comment: Just put the anchor *inside* the cell.

Comment: in many cases, browsers will simply "push" the invalid content to the highest parent that it is a valid element for.  this can cause all sorts of odd formatting glitches, and the issues locating the elements that you are experiencing.  as @Bergi said, put the `a` *inside* the `TD`.

Comment: Btw, instead of trusting your `traverse` script, you should just open the devtools and take a look at the elements using the DOM inspector.

Comment: If you're using the anchor for page position bookmarks, you can also use the `id` attributes. To link to your row for example, you would use `#rowA`

Comment: @Bergi The problem with putting the anchor inside the cell is the anchor top is then the top of whatever it wraps, so if you have a row with two cells, where the relative height of the *content* is indeterminate, then if the anchor wraps the lesser content and the text in the other cell wraps around, jumping to the anchor means the top part of the row is cut off.   I'm aware of the devtools BTW ;), the traverse function was just by way of illustration.  I want to index local anchors inside the table, but those anchors need to wrap rows...

Comment: ...or else I have to write a js function to `scrollBy` the height of the containing element (yeech).  @Phil Thanks! Will try.

Comment: @Claies I feel you have the answer to the Q here (I'm trying to do something that can't be done that way), so if you want to post that please do...for me posterity wise it would focus on what a table is legally composed of.  Didn't know, must work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Claies indicates in the first comment, the problem here is this isn't valid HTML to start with.  The W3C Recommendation describing HTML 5 give the following *content model* ("a normative description of what content **must** be included as children and descendants of the element") [for tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element):

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, followed optionally by a tfoot element, followed by either zero or more tbody elements or one or more tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot element (but there can only be one tfoot element child in total), optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

There's no where prior to the `<tr>` element to legally open the `<a>`.

Fortunately, it isn't necessary to use actual anchor tags to make a local link work:

```
<table id="tableA">
    <tr id="local1">
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
```

`#local1` works as it did before, and the index can be generated from the `<tr>` element.